# How do I get an achievement for breaking the game?

Tags: goat-simulator

Goat Simulator has an achievement called "Involuntary QA", where if the game crashes while you are playing it, you get an achievement.

Twice while trying to pause the game and opening the Steam Console, my game crashed.  I was pretty excited to get the rare game-crashing achievement, but when I checked to see if I had gotten it, both times the achievement failed to register.

How badly do I need to break this game to get the achievement for breaking this game?

Comment: I got it when it crashed while I was playing. If you have an old computer (like me) try opening up a lot of programs, or a lot of webpages, and play the game like that. I can't play games with my firefox open, it lags like hell and causes crashes. probably due to insufficient ram. You can try that. Or try running the game in a VM.

Comment: @miva2 it's definitely not a matter of having an old computer.  Mine isn't the newest, but it's not ancient either.  And like I said in the question, I DID manage to make my game crash, but didn't get the achievement.

Comment: Any known bugs in GS itself that cause crashes will get fixed, so you either need to get "lucky" and find them early, or deliberately install some buggy drivers to induce a crash. Force killing the process may possibly work, depending on the signal used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Steam Achievement guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=243403877&insideModal=1) says you can either Hit "default" in keybindings. Or open the console (default key is "`") and type "BeginBVT".

Comment: I'll try this later tonight.

Comment: I believe the "default" keybindings method has been patched, or it just doesn't work for me.